# Handle Error in RxJs flatMap stream and continue processing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using [RxJs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) in an Angular 2 application to fetch data from an API for multiple pages in parallel and save any failed requests for future re-try.

To do so, I want to catch errors generated by flatMap-ing [http get](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html#!#get-anchor) requests (code below) and continue with further stream processing. In case of error, my current solution causes stream to discontinue.

```
Rx.Observable.range(1, 5)
   .flatMap(pageNo => {
              params.set('page', ''+pageNo);
              return this.http.get(this.API_GET, params)
                        .catch( (err) => {
                                  //save request
                                  return Rx.Observable.throw(new Error('http failed')); 
                          });
    })
    .map((res) => res.json());
```

Let's say in above example, HTTP request for page 2 and 3 fails. I want to handle error (save failed request later retry) for both these request and let other requests continue and get mapped to json().

I tried using `.onErrorResumeNext` instead of catch, but I am unable to make this work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your catch, don't return an `Observable.throw`, then it should continue the stream as desired.

If you want to propagate the information to the outer stream, you could use an `return Observable.of("Error: Foo.Bar");` for example.

Or log the error inside the `catch` and return an `Observable.empty()` to have the outer stream basically ignore the error.

In other words, just chain this:

`.catch(error => Rx.Observable.of(error));`

```js
const stream$ = Rx.Observable.range(1, 5)
    .flatMap(num => {
      return simulateRest(num)
             .catch(error => {
                 console.error(error);
                 return Rx.Observable.empty();
             });
      });
             
stream$.subscribe(console.log);

// mocking-fn for simulating an error
function simulateRest(num) {
    if (num === 2) {
        return Rx.Observable.throw("Error for request: " + num);
    }
  
    return Rx.Observable.of("Result: " + num);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to be working. Error is logged only for the first request that failed.

Comment: How are you logging the errors? In a simple subscribe?

Comment: No, I am logging the error in above mentioned code where `//save request` is written

Comment: I've added an example code-snipped how it could work